# Problems adding marker to google maps in browser

Tags: google-maps-api-3, marker

I want to add a marker on google maps, and I have this code

```
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=myKey&sensor=true">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(56.33481154165235, 11.107177734375),
      zoom: 7,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
    setMarker();
  }

  // Function for adding a marker to the page.
function addMarker(location) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map
    });
}

// Testing the addMarker function
function setMarker() {
       CentralPark = new google.maps.LatLng(55.671389288295465, 12.5601196289062);
       addMarker(CentralPark);
}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

This shows the map, but not the markers.

In advance, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var marker,
    CentralPark = new google.maps.LatLng(55.671389288295465, 12.5601196289062);

function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(56.33481154165235, 11.107177734375),
        zoom: 7,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: CentralPark,
        map: map,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `map` is a local variable within your initialize function so it's not available from other functions.  Make that a global variable.

Or alternatively pass the map object as a parameter through to your setMarker / addMarker functions.

Also I'm not sure why you've got addMarker and setMarker as separate functions (unless you're going to expand on these later with some more functionality which explains why you'd split them up this way).  I've combined them into one in this answer, although technically there's nothing wrong with your approach (it's just the non-global `map` that was your problem).

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=myKey&sensor=true">
</script>
<script>
  // make this global:
  var map;

  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(56.33481154165235, 11.107177734375),
      zoom: 7,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
    addMarker();
  }

  // Function for adding a marker to the page.
function addMarker() {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(55.671389288295465, 12.5601196289062),
        map: map
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```